# Pandas groupby two columns, include all possible values of column 2 per group

Tags: python, pandas

I'm sure this is a duplicate but I cant find it.

I have this data frame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['Sweden','A',5],
                        ['Sweden','A',10],
                        ['Norway','B',4],
                        ['Norway','C',5]],
                  columns=['Country','Class','Value'])
print(df)

  Country Class  Value
0  Sweden     A      5
1  Sweden     A     10
2  Norway     B      4
3  Norway     C      5
```

I want to groupby Country and Class and find their sum, so i try:

```
df.groupby(['Country','Class']).sum()
               Value
Country Class       
Norway  B          4
        C          5
Sweden  A         15
```

But I want all possible Classes to be included for each Country, like this

```
               Value

Country Class       
Norway  B          4
        C          5
        A         na
Sweden  A         15
        B         na
        C         na
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1**
`unstack` and then `stack` again.

```
df.groupby(['Country','Class']).sum().unstack().stack(dropna=False)

               Value
Country Class       
Norway  A        NaN
        B        4.0
        C        5.0
Sweden  A       15.0
        B        NaN
        C        NaN
```

---

**Option 2**
Another option would be to `reindex` with a constructed `MultiIndex`.

```
v = df.groupby(['Country','Class']).sum()
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.Country.unique(), df.Class.unique()])

v.reindex(idx)

          Value
Sweden A   15.0
       B    NaN
       C    NaN
Norway A    NaN
       B    4.0
       C    5.0
```