# How to create a groupby of two columns with all possible combinations and aggregated results

Tags: python, pandas

I want to group a large dataframe over two or more columns and aggregate the other columns. I use groupby but realised after some time that `groupby(label1, label2)` only creates rows for existing combinations of label1 and label2. Example:

```
lijst = [['a', 1, 3],
         ['b', 2, 6],
         ['a', 2, 7],
         ['b', 2, 2],
         ['a', 1, 8]]
data = pd.DataFrame(lijst, columns=['letter', 'cijfer', 'getal'])
data['Aantal'] = 0
label1 = 'letter'
label2 = 'cijfer'
df = data.groupby([label1, label2]).agg({'Aantal': 'count', 'getal': sum})
```

Result:

```
               Aantal  getal
letter cijfer              
a      1            2     11
       2            1      7
b      2            2      8
```

And I wanted something like:

```
               Aantal  getal
letter cijfer              
a      1            2     11
       2            1      7
b      1          NaN    NaN
       2            2      8
```

I tried [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48485275/pandas-groupby-two-columns-include-all-possible-values-of-column-2-per-group) and several others but they all don't handle the case of having to aggregate many columns (sorry if I haved missed it).

The only solution I can thing of is making a template DataFrame from:

```
 template = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([data[label1].unique(), data[label2].unique()]), columns=df.columns)
```

and next copy all data over from df. That seems to me a very tedious solution. Is there a better solution to get what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = df.unstack().stack(dropna=False)
print (df)
               Aantal  getal
letter cijfer               
a      1          2.0   11.0
       2          1.0    7.0
b      1          NaN    NaN
       2          2.0    8.0
```

Or another idea with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df = df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels))
print (df)
               Aantal  getal
letter cijfer               
a      1          2.0   11.0
       2          1.0    7.0
b      1          NaN    NaN
       2          2.0    8.0
```